# Use enter key for confirming suggestions in Ace liveautocomplete

Tags: ace-editor

How can I override behavior of Enter key to confirm Ace's liveautocomplte?

I have autocomplete enabled:

```
editor.setOptions({
  fontFamily: 'Source Code Pro',
  enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
  enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
  enableSnippets: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way is to modify Ace source code. It is set to false in https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/40a9c308b9353ccc867b8126e119e2d47644702c/lib/ace/ext/language_tools.js#L174